# Setting the CPU governor in CM13?

Tags: cyanogenmod, overclocking

Anyone know what happened to this setting? I can't seem to find it any more. Has it been removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, regardless if it was removed you can alway use apps like kernel adiutor: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grarak.kerneladiutor&hl=en
This app and similar ones will let you control CPU/GPU governors and much more, presumably you have root access and have compatible SoC that can be controlled by the app.